# Two dimensional 3 bit parity check

Tags: computer-networks, digital-circuits

Can someone explain how do we find these parity bit errors?
[image]

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the source of this image.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Please provide context about what code is being used here.  Please tell us what research you've done.  You should be consulting other references before asking here.  A slide deck is a poor substitute for reading a proper textbook.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your code works in the following way:

- The input is an $n \times m$ bit matrix.
- You add a parity bit to each row, chosen so that the parity of the new row is even.
- You add a parity bit to each column, chosen so that the parity of the new column is even.
- You end up with an $(n+1) \times (m+1)$ bit matrix in which the parity of each row and column is even.

Suppose now that between 1 and 3 errors occurred. There must be either a row or a column in which *exactly* 1 error occurred (I'll let you figure out why). This row or column will have odd parity, and so you will be able to detect that an error occurred.